# Error: Component definition is missing display name react/display-name with React.forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

I have defined a checkbox like below:

```
export const IndeterminateCheckbox = forwardRef(
    ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
      const defaultRef = useRef()
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef
  
      useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate])
  
      return (<input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />);
    }
);
```

For which I am getting above lint error. I searched for multiple places but could not find how better I can define the `IndeterminateCheckbox` to avoid that error.

Comment: Add `/* eslint-disable react/display-name */`

Answer (score 2):

Short of disabling the `react/display-name` lint rule (globally or for this line specifically), you can simply pass a named function (rather than an anonymous one) to the `forwardRef` call.

```js
export const IndeterminateCheckbox = forwardRef(
    function Checkbox({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) {
        const defaultRef = useRef()
        const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef
  
        useEffect(() => {
            resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate
        }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate])
  
        return (<input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />);
    }
);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Better than disabling the lint rule